# Create a New Hard Drive Partition in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, laptop, partitioning

I got a dell inspiron laptop with 500 GB Hard Drive with Windows 8 pre installed. There is only one partition (C). OS installed on this partition.

I want to partition C drive. What is the best way to partition it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to partition 1 TB hard disk in Dell laptop without reformatting?](http://superuser.com/questions/506015/how-to-partition-1-tb-hard-disk-in-dell-laptop-without-reformatting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is the Disk Management applet. Right click on 'My Computer' and click 'Manage', then on the left hand side, storage > Disk Management.

[image]

Right click on the C:\ Partition, and select 'Shrink Volume...' - Reduce the partition down to the size that you want your new partition, and click 'Shrink.'

Now, in the new unallocated space, right click and format it however you'd like!